# Angular material animate flex changes

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, flexbox, angular-material

I am trying to animate dynamic changes in flex properties for blocks using AngularJS and Angular Material.

I am a bit stuck on how to accomplish an effect where the flex boxes are smoothly resized and pushed out of the way.

Here is a codepen illustrating the situation http://codepen.io/mattmoo/pen/rrmByq

```
<div ng-app="demo" ng-controller="appCtrl">

  <div ng-repeat="size in sizes">
    {{size}}
  </div>

  <div layout="row" layout-wrap class="demo-content" >
    <div ng-repeat="size in sizes" class="flex-{{size}}">
      [flex={{size}}]
    </div>
  </div>

  <input type="text" ng-model="sizes[1]">

  <select ng-model="sizes[1]" ng-options="option for option in options">
</select>

</div>
```

Currently it seems that a new div is created during the transition, as opposed to the div being resized. How can I achieve the effect I am after?

(There are a couple of bugs with the codepen, e.g. cannot have two flexes the same size, select box doesn't work for some values).